# Firefox Webdriver, add website cookies exception?

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver, selenoid

I have a Selenoid Firefox container running some tests but new browser versions are giving me issues.

Since Firefox 103.0 Cross-site tracking cookies are blocked by default and I am looking for a way to add a website exception in Privacy & Security > Cookies and Site Data using Firefox capabilities / Options but nothing seems to do the trick.

A good example of website that causes issues is https://teams.microsoft.com where firefox will now ask you if you "Really want to accept cookies from there ?" which I am trying to bypass by setting website exception in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Done it by selecting a profile at geckodriver start instead of letting it generate one: Add     `args: ["-profile", "/binary/nameoffirefoxprofile"]` to capabilities pref in your code. For this you need to get a firefox profile folder and copy it to your container first. If this works it will replace the generated `rust_mozprofile_someID` of geckodriver.